# Placement of `PlotLabels` in `ComplexListPlot[]`

Tags: plotting, output-formatting

In this example, would like the label $\gamma_a$ to appear below the line segment.

```
Subscript[\[Gamma], a] = ComplexListPlot[{1/4, 1/2}, 
PlotRange -> {-(1/4) - I/4, 3/4 + I}, 
Frame -> True, Axes -> False, Joined -> True, 
PlotLabels -> 
Placed["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Gamma]\), \(a\)]\)", {Scaled[.5], 
 Below}]]; Show[Subscript[\[Gamma], a]]
```

Without `Scaled[.5]` it is below, but a bit too far away from the segment.

Here is how *Mathematica* (Version 12.2) draws it:

[image]

Comment: I can reproduce it in 12.2, but this seems to be fixed in 12.3. Can you update, or do you need a workaround?

Comment: An easy way to control the spacing is to use `Text` in an `Epilog` rather than `PlotLabels`, i.e., `Epilog -> {Text[HoldForm[ Subscript[γ, a]], {0.4, -0.05}]}`

Comment: @LL, Yes, will have to download 12.3, and wait awhile as it installs.  Thank you very much!   Also wondering why `Callout` works in some cases for `ComplexListPlot` and `ComplexContourPlot`, but could not get it to work in this case.  Again, will have to try 12.3.

Comment: @BobHanlon,  Yes, thank you!  That works beautiful, and we can tweak the "label" to be exactly where we want it!   Am happy with this.  Is it fair to say `Epilog -> {Text[...]}` is more of a low level function whereas `PlotLabels` and `Callout` are higher level and more specialized?

Comment: It does seem that in 12.3 many of the issues seen with labeling complex plots have been fixed (based on 10 minutes of testing).